# Escape PHP in String

Tags: php

I have tried searching for a way to escape php in a string and have been unsuccessful. I basically want to be able to write a string that contains php without php parsing it.

The error:

```
Undefined Variable
```

Code

```
$file = fopen("test.php", "w");
$content = "<?php echo $somevariable; ?>";
fwrite($file, $content);
```

*updated to show variable in string.

Comment: Use single quotes.

Comment: PHP will not execute embedded PHP. What you have will work exactly as you want: The characters `<`, `?`, `p` etc... will get written out to the file.

Comment: Uhh what do you want? Your code looks fine.

Comment: What's the problem here?  `$content` will contain a string (that happens to have `<?php` tags), it won't be parsed.  See: https://eval.in/189032

Comment: @GergoErdosi: That won't change anything in this *specific* example.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, the single quotes seem to have done it.  I didn't mention above that I had a variable in the string that was causing an undefined variable error.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Example is not clear. If the real code contains variables, single quotes will help.

Comment: Well, that makes the negative and close votes easy then; the entire premise behind this question is rubbish.

Comment: @GergoErdosi: That's true.  The example was unclear.  :-)

Comment: @GergoErdosi: You should make that an answer :-D

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, I tried doing a google search on this but couldn't find much, although I may have not been searching for the right terms.  I was searching for escaping php in a string.  Anyways thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in double quotes are [expanded](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded. See string parsing for details.

Use either single quotes:

```
$content = '<?php echo $somevariable; ?>';
```

or a [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
$content = <<<'EOD'
<?php echo $somevariable; ?>
EOD;
```

> A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc.